# Exporting image as plane to fbx

Tags: export, image, .fbx

I am currently having trouble with exporting a 3D model with image as plane. This is the original appearance of it in blender, but after exporting it to fbx, it looks like a blank piece of paper.

How can I retain its original appearance in 3D export? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: I think you might need to move textures manually, not sure which folder they should go to though.

Comment: How do I move textures manually? I'm sorry, I'm just a noob in using Blender. Thanks

Comment: I mean the images. On your filesystem. I am a beginner too, but I think every time I have exported to fbx the textures have just been saved as some kind of relative path inside it, not as an embedded image.